# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' just in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

I have a .py script which I have open in Virtual Studio Code. One of my libraries (bs4) is not getting imported successfully, it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I've tried to pip install bs4 in my command line, but the library was already there.

However, I've run the exact same script in Jupyter Notebooks (installed by anaconda package) and the library existed and the script worked as expected.

How can I get VS Code to use the same libraries as Jupyter Notebooks is using?

Comment: See this article for selecting your Python environment. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: VS Code by default uses the python interpreter from the standard python installation. Follow the above article specified by @AKX, to change the interpreter VS Code is using to conda.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've selected the base:conda interpreter from my list, but still the code not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the python 3 interpreter:

- Click the interpreter button in the bottom left (bottom blue ribbon): https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H2AL.png
- Try running with the different Python 3 interpreter paths until you find one which works - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY1Ld.png

Comment: Thanks. However, I just have 2 different interpreter paths and none of them work :(

Answer (score 0):

Your system almost certainly has more than one Python installation. Running *pip* from the command line is working with a different version to the one that Visual Studio Code is configured to use

Comment: That would make sense. How can I change the python version Visual Studio Code is configured to use?

Comment: @banana_99 Try to set absolute path to Python Interpreter (to venv where 'bs4' is installed) in VS Code settings. From July 2021 they (Python extension) changed setting name and not all behavior is working as before (setting is not changed in setting file after selecting interpreter from status bar or VS command. See my comment for more details: https://github.com/Almenon/AREPL-vscode/issues/418#issuecomment-899017170

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your IDE is using the correct Python version**
In VSCode, you can press CTRL+Shift+P or (⌘+Shift+P on Mac) to open the command palette

Input: Python select interpreter

Then you can see multiple interperter

Choose Global Interpreter
Restore VSCode and try is it doing well.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this command for installing `bs4` on Visual Studio Code on the terminal:

```
py -m pip install bs4
```

Don't use this:

```
pip install bs4
```

Comment: I assume you are on Windows, where the Python/`pip` installation can be a problem. Because `pip install bs4` is perfectly fine, especially if you are using a virtual environment. The OP's problem is most likely related to using the wrong Python interpreter.